# table in android is not extending?

Tags: android

i have have added rows in tables... but after adding some rows table have stop showing rows even though i have defined some textview....

i have also added touch screen support in both emulator and xml... but still its not working in emulator and mobile both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not really clear to me but I guess you should put the TableLayout into a ScrollView layout.

Without the scrollview "around" the table, rows will go "out of the screen" and you can't scroll down your view